# Improper usage of Indefinite article

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, grammaticality

"Grammarly" tells me that sentence:

> I am a bad table.

is correct, but the following sentence:

> I am a bad trash.

is not correct.
Can you explain me why?

Comment: Trash isn't a countable noun. You can't have "one trash" or "multiple trashes". I don't know why you would call yourself a table though, that's just weird.

Comment: @MicahWindsor It was just a silly example :D, Thanks anyway <3.